# Firebase Security Rules - permission denied when trying to remove data from a tree node

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I've been struggling with some firebase security rules. I've been able to add/update data on a node, but I'm not able to remove it. Here are the rules for my node:

```
"auditions": {
        ".read": "auth !== null",
        "$auditionId": {
         "_geoloc": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "band_id": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "creator_id": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "date_created": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "date_last_updated": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "genres": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "instruments": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "is_deleted": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "objectID": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "type": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "videos": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "audition_id": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "is_new": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "message": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "status": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "user_id": {
           ".write": "auth !== null && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || (data.parent().hasChild('user_id') && data.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('user_id') && newData.parent().child('user_id').val() === auth.uid) || (data.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && data.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid) || (newData.parent().hasChild('creator_id') && newData.parent().child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid))"
         },
         "applications": {
           ".write": "auth !== null"
         }
        }
      }
```

I have it setup this way because there are some more complex rules that are needed on all of the sub-nodes of `$auditionId` except for `applications`.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here with specifying the individual sub-nodes of `$auditionId` where when I go to remove data in my app, I get a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error?

Comment: Have try with 

{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Comment: Yeah but I need to be more granular than that :/

Comment: If you're trying to delete `/auditions/$auditionId` that will indeed fail with these rules, since the user doesn't have permission on that node.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that makes sense. I'm wondering what I should have there then? If I make the write rule to be auth !== null on the `/auditions/$auditionId` node, won't that just override all the deeper rules?

Comment: Yes it will. I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish with having the rules at the lower level. It feels like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) right now. Can you describe in one sentence what the rules are meant to accomplish? The correct implementation typically it easier to discover from that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yeah definitely. So I updated my question to show the actual rules I'm trying to use. Basically, when a user creates an audition, I want to check if they are the creator via the `creator_id` and `user_id` fields in the data. However, there is an instance where I want a field in the audition to be updatable by anyone, and that would be the `applications` node. So essentially, I want to limit writes/updates/deletes to the creators of the auditions, EXCEPT for when updating `/auditions/$applicationId/applications`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to limit writes/updates/deletes to the creators of the auditions, EXCEPT for when updating `/auditions/$applicationId/applications`

That sounds like:

```
auditions": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    "$auditionId": {
        ".write": "auth !== null && (
          (data.exists() && data.child('user_id').val === auth.uid) ||
          (!data.exists() && newData.child('user_id').val() === auth.uid)
        )",
        "applications": {
            ".write": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I love you. That is perfect. Solves a number of my other issues as well <3